# How to calculate the pressure of a trapped, bubble of air 1m below water surface

Tags: pressure, buoyancy, volume

Ahoy hive mind!

The rough scenario I'm looking for some help over is;

- Picture a tub of $\mathrm{10 \ (l) × 5 \ (w) × 2 \ (h)}$ floating in a body of water
- The full mass is $50,000 \ \mathrm{kg}$, so the displaced $50\ \mathrm{m^3}$ of water reaches half way up the tub sides
- Add a mirrored cavity, equivalent to the top, except with only $\mathrm{1\ m}$ vertical walls (structure included in the $50,000\ \mathrm{kg}$ of mass)
- This occurs in freshwater, and at seal level.

[image: FLOODED CAVITY]

Now bubble air into the inverted cavity, filling the entire $50\ \mathrm{m^3}$ and raising the double-tub $1\ \mathrm{m}$ higher in the water, to the point where the top of the trapped air pocket is level with the water surface.

[image: AIR FILLED CAVITY]

**My question :**

How would one go about calculating the pressure of the trapped air?

Any help appreciated! The idea is to hypothesise how vast a submerged tank would be needed to qualify as a realistic, low-pressure, energy stoage reservoir (any further thoughts would also be welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pressure of the air at the bottom is the pressure on top plus the pressure due to the change in height: $p=W/A+\rho_{air}gh$.
You can also calculate that pressure by considering the pressure of the water there:
$p=p_{atmosphere}+\rho_{water}gh$.

From these two you can get both, $p$ and $h$

Comment: Super thanks for that, I was out of my depth (h)!

Comment: @AlexanderForster I am glad it helped!